# On the website: godbolt.org, and only there: how can I use std::thread?

Tags: c++, pthreads

Here is my code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
#include <iostream>

void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < n; ++cnt) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t1 = std::thread(f, 5);
    //t1.join();
    t1 = std::thread(f, 5); // <- should abort if t1.join() is not done
    t1.join();
}
```

For the website, I am using a gcc9.2 executor to see what happens when an un-joined thread is destructed, but this is content of the compiler output tab:

```
Could not execute the program
Compiler returned: 1
Compiler stderr

/tmp/ccjlEO57.o: In function `std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&, void>(void (&)(int), int&)':

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:126: undefined reference to `pthread_create'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also - when I add "-lpthread" to the *Compiler options...* edit box, I get a different error:

```
Program returned: 255
Program stderr

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Please *note* that for this 2nd run, the first `t1.join()` was not commented out (so it should run fine).

Does this mean you can't test anything `std::thread` related on the otherwise incredibly awesome **godbolt.org** website?

Comment: You may need to explicitly add the threads library to your link inputs.

Comment: I have already updated my question - the compiler option does not work.  Could you please unmark this as a duplicate.   It is specifically related to the website:    Godbolt.org and how to make it work there.

Comment: godbolt.org has disabled creating threads. Pay the owner to enable them, use some other service, or get your own computer.

Comment: @n.m. I am sorry if I didn't see something obvious - but I didn't notice anything on the site that explained this.
So I was hoping for confirmation here...    which you provided.
If you add an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: I don't think it's documented anywere, I deduced it from the error message.

Comment: You could try [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cfbc9f8c46be41b) instead. It provides g++ 9.2 currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all likelyhood, thread creation is disabled on godbolt.org on purpose (to prevent denial of service attacks or other abuse), so there is currently no way to use std::thread on that service.

Answer (score 10):

The site [now](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/1910) supports threads. Add `-pthread` to the compiler arguments.

Comment: Pity that std::thread::hardware_concurrency() says only 2.